# Statsmodels package install error using pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I tried to install Statsmodels in python 2.7 using pip. 
It showed me the following error:
"Unable to find vcvarsall.bat".

Can someone help me regarding the same. I am using Windows 8.1 as OS.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: Basically, `statsmodels` includes C code that needs to be compiled. This is painful on Windows. You should either install and configure Visual Studio, OR, more simply, download the correct binary from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#statsmodels.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/):

> Many binaries depend on Numpy-MKL 1.8 and the Microsoft Visual C++
>   2008 (x64, x86, and SP1 for CPython 2.6 to 3.2) or Visual C++ 2010
>   (x64, x86, for CPython 3.3 and 3.4) redistributable packages.

Basically, you either need the above installed OR use the precompiled binaries from the same site. In any case, the installer you're looking for is in [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#statsmodels). Download the appropriate installer for your architecture (x86 or x64). Install. Make sure it's for the appropriate Python version and that it  targets the correct `PYTHONPATH` in your computer.